# Why am I getting an "xxx is already defined" compiler error?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am trying to create multiple threads using variable like threadname1, threadname2,..threadnamen. Instead of giving it as a hard coded value I am trying to do it using a for loop for the n numbers and use that at the end of "threadname" string. It throws some error. How do I fix this issue?

```
public class RunnableExample{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String Name = "";
        String Ip = "";
        for (int i=1; i<=2; i++){
            if(i == 1){
                Name = "irony";
                Ip = "82.209.27.24";
            }
            else{
                Name = "jocky";
                Ip = "98.12.098.56";
            }
            String runname = "threadname" + i;
            RunnableThread runname = new RunnableThread(Name,Ip);
              new Thread(runname).start();
        }

        //RunnableThread threadname1 = new RunnableThread("irony","82.209.27.24");
        //RunnableThread thread4 = new RunnableThread("jocky","98.12.098.56");
        //new Thread(threadname1).start();
        //new Thread(threadname2).start();
        try{

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
bash-3.00# javac RunnableExample.java
RunnableExample.java:43: runname is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
            RunnableThread runname = new RunnableThread(Name,Ip);
```

How do I resolve this issue? Maybe some typecasting is required it seems. I am not sure.

Comment: Don't name variables `Name` or `Ip`.  The first character being uppercased, indicates that the identifier refers to a _class_ and not a field.  Use `name` and `ip` instead.

Answer (score 10):

This is your problem:

```
String runname = "threadname" + i;
RunnableThread runname = new RunnableThread(Name,Ip);
```

You're trying to declare two variables with the same name. You can't do that. Change the name of one of the variables. The names of variables are fixed at compile-time in Java. You can't say "declare a variable with the name of the execution-time value of *this* variable" which is what I think you're trying to do.

If you want a way of accessing multiple values, use a collection or an array. For example, you might want a `List<RunnableThread>` here - add the value to the list in each iteration of your loop.

I'd also *strongly* recommend that you make sure you understand the basics of Java (things like variables and collections) *before* you start try experiment with threading. Threading is complicated and can be very hard to reason about - it's going to be even harder if you're struggling with the core language.

Comment: I understood the problem. I like to use the "threadname + i" to create the new thread. i.e RunnableThread threadname1,2,..n = new RunnableThread(Name,Ip); Could you please guide me. So here for creating five threads instead of writing five time this statement I am trying to do it using a single line. Could you please help me.

Comment: there is no way I know of to create a variable name based on a string, however I agree with Jon Skeet using a List is the best approach

Comment: @Ricks - Your comment implies you do not understand the problem. You are attempting to declare TWO variables with the same name; "runname". Change one of the variable's name and your code will work. I also agree with Jon, though, that you should familiarize yourself more with Java and gain some experience before attempting to use threads. The problem you encountered was a compile-time error and is easily resolved. You said "it throws some error" which indicates you do not understand the Java language.

Comment: "runname" _could_ be a mishearing of a variable named "runnable".

Answer (score 1):

Probably a typo, you wanted to type :

```
String Name = "threadname" + i;
RunnableThread runname = new RunnableThread(Name,Ip);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of your variable containing the thread name :

```
        String threadName = "threadname" + i;
        RunnableThread runname = new RunnableThread(threadName, ip);
```

A good thing to do if you work with Java is to use the Java naming convention. For example all variable start with a lower case.

---

You might have wanted to do this :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RunnableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, RunnableThread> threadMap = new HashMap<String, RunnableThread>();

        String name = "";
        String ip = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                name = "irony";
                ip = "82.209.27.24";
            } else {
                name = "jocky";
                ip = "98.12.098.56";
            }
            String threadName = "threadname" + i;
            RunnableThread thread = new RunnableThread(name, ip);
            new Thread(thread).start();

            threadMap.put(threadName, thread);
        }

        threadMap.get("threadname1").getIp();
    }
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Oracle.com - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: I wanted the variable runname to be runname1,runname2..runnamen. Not the passing parameters to the RunnableThread method. Please help.

Comment: @Ricks: As we've said, you can't do that. The name of the variable will be exactly what you write in the source code - it's not evaluated at execution time. You should be using a collection.

Comment: Thanks Colin HEBERT. This is what I am looking for the final edited code by you. I am all set now. Thanks

Comment: I mean the final edited code by you is the real requirement for me. May be I did not convery that correctly. Sorry for the trouble to all of you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I won't bother pointing out the problem of your posted code because others already have. I will however suggest you do not use a for loop if you are going to be doing if checks inside it to see which iteration you are on. This is not a good practice. Infact, a non iterative solution is actually less lines of code and cleaner...

```
Thread ironyThread = new RunnableThread("irony", "82.209.27.24");
Thread jockyThread = new RunnableThread("jocky", "98.12.098.56");
ironyThread.start();
jockyThread.start();
```

Something like that will do what you are trying. I know you said that you want it to handle N threads. My solution would still be cleaner that the pattern you are following; adding an if check around each iteration for different threadName values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is just a sample code for which i am working on. I will be reading a input.txt file and it has around 1000 names and its ip address. I need to read those 1000 names,ip and create a thread to do some other task. So I am tyring to do this in a single line of thread creation. Could you please suggest me how can i do this.